# Spring boot app keeps crashing in production

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment, jvm, jhipster

I built java web application using jHipster (based on Spring boot), created production war and copied it to Amazon Lightsail server (30 days free version).

When I run it - anytime in a day - it is always down next day morning. My Log file has no message about something went wrong.

I run it with this command: `setsid /home/ec2-user/teamly/teamly-0.10.0-BETA.war > /home/ec2-user/teamly/teamly-log`

I am really desperate, because I do not know how to investigate this problem.

Server is up, it's not the problem. So are there some memory leaks, resources issues, jvm issue or is my run command wrong? Traffic on app is very low, so I doubt it (moreover it falls in the night when all users sleeps).

One thing seems strange to me and it is the number of processes started with the app. See the image below.

Moreover when I keep refreshing the page, MEM of the process is increasing. Sometimes even 0.1 per refresh. But it stops on some value.

Thank you for any advice. I could provide more info, just do not know what is necessary right now.

[image]

Comment: Your command looks wrong to me as you don't specify prod profile or do you set it using a config file or environment variable? Also what is your logging configuration? Are you able to run in prod profile locally and investigate, it'll be easier.

Comment: When you build with prod parameter it will use prod config so it should be ok.

Comment: Are you sure? We're talking about 2 different things: maven prod profile (build) and spring prod profile (runtime) that is usually activated using `--spring.profiles.active=prod`. In your case, I think your app runs under default profile but you can easily verify it in log file.

Comment: Log file says The following profiles are active: prod , Web application configuration, using profiles: prod. But even if u are using dev profie or some kind of default profile, your app should not fall by itself after one day right?!

Comment: Right, it should fail at startup. Could be same issue as https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6490

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was happening because of lack of resources available on my Lightsail server. Probably lack of RAM. When I moved that exactly same implementation to another service provider, problem disappeared.